# How to show that $\lim\limits _{z\to2\pi k\cdot i}\frac{z}{e^{z}-1} $ doesn't exist

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I want to show that for all $0\neq k\in\mathbb{Z}$ the limit $\lim\limits _{z\to2\pi k\cdot i}\frac{z}{e^{z}-1}$ does not exist but I'm not sure how to do so formally.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Choose an easy path to $2\pi i k$ like $z(t)=t+2\pi k i$ and let $t$ go to $0$. $e^t-1=O(t)$

Comment: If I look at the limit $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t+2\pi ki}{e^{t}-1}$ I would want to split it into two limits the latter of which $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{2\pi ki}{e^{t}-1}$ does not exist. But I can't split the limit unless both of the limits exist so it's not sufficient that one of the limits doesn't exist in order to show that the limit of the sum doesn't exist. 
It's obvious to me that the one sided limits exist and are different but that's what I'm not sure how to show.

Comment: For any complex number $w$ one has $|w|\geq |Im(w)|$. If $Im(w)$ diverges for $t\rightarrow 0$ then...In this setting, take $Im w(t)=\frac{2\pi k i}{e^t-1}$

Comment: But if $k=0$, the limit *does* exist.

Comment: Ye I should have made en exception for $k=0$, I didn't notice that. I'm still not sure on how to show that for $k\neq0$ the limit $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t+2\pi ki}{e^{t}-1}$ doesn't exist (that is to show the one sided limits are different).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach $ 2\pi ki$ along the imaginary axis using $z(t)=2\pi k i t$. Your limit is then

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{2\pi k i t}{1+2\pi k i t+\frac{(2\pi k i t)^2}{2}+\dots -1}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}
\frac{1}{1+\frac{2\pi k i t}{2}+\dots }=1, $$

as $e^x-1=O(x)$ for $x\rightarrow 0$.

On the other hand, choosing to approach $ 2\pi ki$ along the real axis using $z(t)=t+2\pi k i$ one arrives at

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{t+2\pi k i }{1+ t+\frac{ t^2}{2}+\dots -1}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}
\frac{t+2\pi k i}{t+\frac{ t^2}{2}+\dots  }=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} ~\omega(t), $$

with $\omega(t)=\frac{1}{1+O(t)}+\frac{2\pi k }{O(t)}i$. The above limit diverges as $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\operatorname{im}(\omega(t))$ diverges.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to show that the last limit diverges.

Comment: When you write that the limit diverges do you mean that it exists and is infinite or that it doesn't exist at all?
Because in the case of $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t+2\pi ki}{e^{t}-1}$ this limit doesn't diverge to infinity rather it doesn't exist at all, the one sided limits are both infinite but of different sign.

Comment: I mean that the limit $z\rightarrow 2\pi k i $ ($k\neq 0$) does not exist, as it admits limit values depending on the path chosen to approach $2\pi k i$. The limits $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\operatorname{im}(\omega(t))$ and $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}|\omega(t)|$ diverge to infitnity.